# Error using Geocoder package in flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter

Using this package: [Geocoder](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/geocoder)

I keep getting this error: `'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>'`
in the distant_google.dart file at this line: `List<Map> results = data["results"];`

Any idea what the issue is?

Comment: try `var results = data["results"];`

Comment: after doing that it says this: '(Map<dynamic, dynamic>) => Map<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic) => dynamic' of 'f'